# Responses of Raavya to Rokeach

Tags: rishonim, responsa

[R. Elazar of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) (author Sefer Rokeach) sent questions to [R. Eliezer ben Yoel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Joel_HaLevi)
(known as Raavyah). These are recorded by Raavyah (ch. 151). responses to some of the questions are recorded there.

I seem to remember seeing a a published version of responses of Raavyah to the author of the Rokeach. Where can these be found, and do they include additional answers, not included in the published Raavyah?

Comment: The title "Responses of Raavya" should not be corrected to "responsa". The question addresses a single responsum, consisting of multiple responses to multiple questions. Just explaining what looks like a typo so save any overzealous editors time.